# How to refresh intellisense in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was searching my problem and not found answer on other question about SQL Server 2005.

I tried `Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache` and also <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> as well, but still I am getting this error.

Is there any solution for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: when I run querry on my DB then get error of `Invalid Object Name`

Comment: If you get that error, it's not intellisense that needs updating, the object really doesn't exist. Are you sure you're connected to the right database/instance, and looking in the right schema?

Comment: yes I am sure, bcoz there is only one database in the server

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code which causes the error (as formatted text please, not picture)

Comment: from my code all the queries are working and when I run the same query on Server the `Invalid Object Name`

Comment: @HoneyBadger is right, if you're getting the error `Invalid Object Name` then the object doesn't exist. no SQL Server (including 2005) has one database; by default it has 4: `master`,`msdb`,`tempdb` and `model`. I would hazard a guess you're using the wrong database (probably `master`)..

Comment: my question is only about how to refresh Intellisence in Sql sever 2005, if I edit my question then other will mark as duplicate bcoz this error is describe and resolved in other versions of server but not in 2005

Comment: then how to change the database?

Comment: `USE YourDatabaseName;`

Comment: Thanks alot, I change the `db` and all is fine now

Comment: By the way, if at all possible, I strongly advise to upgrade to a more recent version of sql server.

Comment: actually I am fresh grad, before I was using `14` version in my semester projects, now I join an org they are using `2005` :( , so I have to work in this org. They are also using old tech :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

I beg your pardon I was wrong, I was running the query in `master-db` now I change my db and run the query on `sql-server-2005` and it works.